# How to open an android app from my website with a dialog box?

Tags: java, php, android, html

I tried this

> intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;

and it's working.
but i need a dialog box like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XQKk.jpg) plz some one help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put, an event on the click, and open an modal like the image, if the user click on button 'open' so you redirect the user to your url `intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;`